# Merging Columns with separator ',' and don't render separator if no value exist

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm merging data into column A like this:

=B2&","&C2&","&D2

```
A        |  B | C  | D 
ES,,        ES      
DE,NL,IT    DE  NL  IT
CH,,        CH      
CH,,        CH      
DE,BE,AT    DE  BE  AT
FR,BE,      FR  BE  
CH,SG,      CH  SG  
AT,CH,ES    AT  CH  ES
```

Yet, if there are no values in a column it appends e.g. extra  ,,  what I don't want. So result should be like

```
A        |  B | C  | D 
ES          ES      
DE,NL,IT    DE  NL  IT
CH          CH      
CH          CH      
DE,BE,AT    DE  BE  AT
FR,BE       FR  BE  
CH,SG       CH  SG  
AT,CH,ES    AT  CH  ES
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2016 you can use the [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function to concatenate with a delimiter which also allows you to skip blank cells.

For example:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:D2)
```

Will return:

```
A        |  B  |  C  |  D 
ES          ES      
DE,NL,IT    DE    NL    IT
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula `=B2&IF(C2<>"",","&C2,"")&IF(D2<>"",","&D2,"")...`

Or

**Concatenate cells ignore or skip blanks with User Defined Function**

If there are multiple cells needed to be combined, the above formula will be too complex to execute, so, you can use the following User Defined Function to solve it.

1. Hold down the Alt + F11 keys in Excel, and it opens the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.
2. Click Insert > Module, and paste the following macro in the Module Window.

VBA code: Concatenate cells ignore blanks:

```
Function Concatenatecells(ByVal ConcatArea As Range, Optional ByVal Separator As String = "/") As String
'updateby Extendoffice 20151103
  For Each n In ConcatArea: nn = IIf(n = "", nn & "", nn & n & Separator): Next
  Concatenatecells = Left(nn, Len(nn) - Len(Separator))
End Function
```

3. Save and close this code window, go back to the worksheet, then enter this formula: =Concatenatecells(range, [separator])
   ex : =Concatenatecells(A1:A5, ", ")
   ex : =Concatenatecells(D11:d52)

Comment: Andreas is right ... should be =B2&IF(C2<>"",","&C2,"")&IF(D2<>"",","&D2,"") .... otherwise the first value comes twice. But it works ... thanks. (although I have like 20 columns and the formula is huge :-) )

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:D2)=1,B2,IF(COUNTA(B2:D2)=2,B2&","&C2,B2&","&C2&","&D2))
```